# Finding each record having second largest date for each `key' column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

With below code I'm able to get every **key** with max key_date value.

```
SELECT *
FROM `log`
GROUP BY `key`
ORDER BY `key_date` DESC
```

But how can i get every records matching ***second*** largest date?

```
id  Key   key_date
--------------------
1   Key1  10/10/2010
2   Key1  10/10/2009
3   Key2  10/10/2011
4   Key2  10/10/2012
5   Key1  10/10/2008
```

I need to match  record 2 (second largest among key1) and 3 (second largest among key2)

```
2   Key1  10/10/2009
3   Key2  10/10/2011
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: I need it work on both 5.7.21 and 5.6.40

Comment: My answer will work for those versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM `log` l 
WHERE key_date = (SELECT l1.`key_date`
                  FROM  `log` l1
                  WHERE l1.`key` = l.`key`
                  ORDER BY l1.`key_date` DESC
                  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you're using MySQL 8.0 or higher - I think a windowing function would be a good way to do this.

```
SELECT id, Key, Key_date
    FROM
    (
    SELECT id, KEY, key_date, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Key ORDER BY key_date DESC) AS row_n
    FROM log
    ) a1
    WHERE row_n = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any MySQL Version. Later versions will support windowed functions.

Edited for Raymond's input, but for versions >=8 ... probably just use windowed functions anyway.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe157c/9

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA (
    ID_Field VARCHAR(100),
    Test_Integer INTEGER
  );

INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('1',1);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('1',2);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('1',3);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('2',5);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('2',6);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('2',-1);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('2',4);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('3',1);
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES ('3',2);

SELECT ID_Field,
       Test_Integer
  FROM (SELECT TD1.ID_field,
               TD1.Test_Integer,
               COUNT(TD2.ID_Field) + 1 rn
          FROM TEST_DATA TD1
          LEFT
          JOIN TEST_DATA TD2
            ON TD1.ID_Field = TD2.ID_Field
           AND TD1.Test_Integer < TD2.Test_Integer
         GROUP
            BY TD1.ID_Field,
               TD1.Test_Integer
         ORDER
            BY TD1.ID_Field,
               TD1.Test_Integer
       ) TMP
 WHERE TMP.rn = 2;
```

Comment: Side note: "This will work for any MySQL Version" Be adviced MySQL 8.0 does not automatic order the GROUP BY annymore..Trusting that GROUP BY is sorting is trusting a deprecated feature which is deprecated since MySQL 5.7.. see demo MySQL 5.7 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a9VYgUKQAg3yAjv3FpcAei/0 vs MySQL 8.0 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a9VYgUKQAg3yAjv3FpcAei/1  "Later versions will support windowed functions." True in MySQL 8.0 you should use a window function.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the heads up, didn't realize that.